# In PowerPoint, how do you replace a decimal separator with a comma

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, format, localization

A few slides in my PowerPoint are in a different language and I having difficulties changing percentage numbers to the format required by the language.

In the category `Percentage` how do I change the  format Code form `0.0%` (3.8% 10.6% 13.0%) to something like `0,0%` (3,8% 10,6% 13,0%)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the decimal separator just for PowerPoint.

PowerPoint uses the separators defined in the operating system for the language region.
Changing them requires changes that are permanent and system-wide.

Please note that usually you need to restart PowerPoint in order to let the
changes take effect.

Comment: So I'll have to create a custom string and insert it into it. Thanks for letting me know so I can stop digging and instead I'll start working on an OpenXML script.

Comment: "Changing them requires changes that are permanent and system-wide."  Or at least permanent until you change them back. But harrymc's answer is right on target.

Comment: Your answer is proper but I have also found an improper solution.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I have found is multiplying my data set by 1000 and using `0\,0 \%` as the format code. Not the prettiest and requires a bit more logic when using openXML to create slides in both Enlgish and French.

The French Graphs are identical to the English ones except that the selected data is a column that multiplies the column containing the original values by 1000.